# php ajax auto login without form action

Tags: php, ajax

php ajax auto login works well in form action, but is it possible to execute without form action?

```
$email = 'xxx@gmail.com';
$password = 'password';

<script>
    var user = <?php $email; ?>;
    var pass = <?php $password; ?>;
    console.log(email=' + user + ', password=' + pass);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.example.com/login',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ email: user, password: pass }),
        success: function(data, status) {
            // do something after login
            console.log('success');
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });

    return false;

    </script>
```

Comment: What you mean with `form action`

Comment: you can just use `data: { email: user, password: pass },`

Comment: this code works well in user input form action <form action="www.example.com/login" method="post">, but my question is possible to execute without form action?

Comment: Then .. from where you will get username and password ?

Comment: show more code how its working now and what you want to get

Comment: var user = <?php $email; ?>;
var pass = <?php $password; ?>;

Comment: You cannot send ajax from client side to server side without some event, in your case you just can use another event instead of form submit.

Comment: login page authenticating after click form action click submit button. but manual php variable in ajax not running.

Answer (score 0):

You should use GET method instead.

```
$email = 'xxx@gmail.com';
$password = 'password';
<script>
var user = <?php $email; ?>;
var pass = <?php $password; ?>;
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/login',
    type: 'GET', //send it through get method
    data: { 
    email: user, 
    password: pass
    },
    success: function(response) {
    //Do Something
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
    //Do Something to handle error
    }
});
</script>
```

Then check in your login page if email and password parameters have been set by GET or POST methods.

```
<?php 

if (isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['password']) || isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
// check your database and take actions.
}else{
// do nothing and show the post from again.
}

?>
```

Comment: hello sir, my basic question is without form action get or post method. In one php file directly call ajax with username and password  for login credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Following code may work on page load if the username and password is auto-filled.

I hope this may help you.

```
<script>

 $(document).ready(function(){

    var user = $('[name="username"]').val();
    var pass = $('[name="password"]').val();

    if(user !== '' && pass!== ''){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.YourUrl.com/login',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 
                email: user, 
                password: pass
            },
            success: function(response) {
                   //When successfully logged in
            },
            error: function() {
                  //If error on server side script
            }
        });

      }

   });
```

As here we have created POST request, you need to handle is by $_POST server side.